# Initialize a String using a Character Array

Tags: c++, string

Suppose I have a Character Array and I'd like to convert it to a string. Is it possible to initialize the string using that character array without looping through the array and adding each character to the string?

Comment: No. No matter what you do, the string class will do that behind the scenes.

Comment: ***Show code.*** *(Otherwise, we're only guessing at the details of your question.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign them:

```
std::string str = char_array;
```

Of course that still loops through the string, internally. No avoiding this (but it’s very efficient).

Comment: I'm not sure what's the definition of "character array" here, but if it's not zero-terminated, you may also need to supply length.

Comment: I had mainly hoped to avoid writing the loop myself, as I thought there'd be a more efficient way to do it as far as code writing goes. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Yeah, my answer is hardly complete but I’ve got a hunch that this is exactly what OP needs.

Comment: May well be the case, just commenting for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `std::string::string(char const*)` constructor, which works since C-style arrays implicitly decay to pointers:

```
char my_character_array[] = "Hello, world!";
std::string my_string(my_character_array);
```

Make sure the array contains a null character, otherwise the behaviour is undefined.

---

If you have an `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of a C-style array, use the following:

```
std::string my_string(my_character_array.begin(), my_character_array.end());
```

If you already have an `std::string` object, take a look at [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Answer (score 1):

See [Constructor 4 & 5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

```
char s[] ={'a','b','c', '\0'};

std::string str(s);
```